# How to read text from input box on web server and use it in shell/Python script?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Is there any way to read string from input box of a simple HTML document and run command on a server with that string?

My case is:
I have raspberry pi with USB hard disk in my network and I want to host a simple website with only one field. I want to have access to this site from any device in my network and just paste there link to a file from the Internet and get that file downloaded directly to a raspberry pi's hard drive. Is it even possible? How can I do it?